# Wifi downlink very slow with MSI B450 Gaming Pro Carbon AC

Tags: networking, wifi, kubuntu

Today, I assembled a PC using the MSI B450 Gaming Pro Carbon AC as its motherboard. This motherboard comes with wifi. Already before installing Kubuntu 18.04, I noticed that the downlink is terribly slow (highest about 1 Mbit/s, often way below). This stayed the same after booting into the installed operating system.

The wifi's uplink is not affected. It is much faster than the downlink. When I connect my computer and my laptop via a LAN cable and share the laptop's internet connection (same wifi network) with the computer, it has a fast downlink too.

I connected a cheap old wifi stick to the computer. The wifi stick is so cheap and old that it is quite limited itself but even it pulls data with over 60 Mbit/s.

Kubuntu does not list any additional drivers to install.

How can I improve the speed of the on-board wifi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the same issue on Mint 19.1. Kernel 4.20 helped me. I used the "ukuu" tool to update the kernel. 
Maybe some of the earlier version works too, but I have jumped to 4.20 directly. Also, make sure you are using the latest BIOS.

Comment: Thank you very much! Merely updating UEFI did the trick! :)